# Смена прозрачности спрайта

Tags: unity3d

Как программно поменять прозрачность картинки (спрайта)? Есть кнопка управления персонажем, надо убавить прозрачность

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно у компонента `SpriteRenderer` получить значение свойства `color`, изменить поле `a` у полученного объекта и записать цвет обратно в свойство `color`.

Пример скрипта на C#:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpriteAlphaChanger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public SpriteRenderer _sprite = null; // Сюда в инспекторе нужно перетащить спрайт.
    public KeyCode _key = KeyCode.C; // Здесь в инспекторе нужно выбрать клавишу. 
    public float Speed = 1f; // Задает скорость изменения цвета в единицах в секунду.

    void Update () 
    {
        // Получаем цвет спрайта.
        var color = _sprite.color;

        // Проверяем, нажата ли клавиша.
        // Возможно, будет лучше настроить клавишу в Edit->Project Settings->Input и использовать GetButton. Потребуется изменить и поле _key.
        if (Input.GetKey (_key)) 
            // Уменьшаем значение альфы с заданной скоростью. Не забываем Time.deltaTime.
            color.a -= Speed * Time.deltaTime;
        else
            // Увеличиваем значение альфы с заданной скоростью. Не забываем Time.deltaTime.
            color.a += Speed * Time.deltaTime; 

        // Не даем значению выйти за границы, для цвета это (0, 1).
        color.a = Mathf.Clamp(color.a, 0, 1); 

        // Задаем спрайту новый цвет.
        _sprite.color = color; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!